# G_Malloc error for Grass module(r.stream.extract) in R

Tags: raster, r, grass-gis, windows, 64bit

I am having a big issue of this G_malloc Error while using a module of Grass (6.4.4) (r.stream.extract) in R. Initially I thought my computers configuration was low, So I switched to 8gb Ram 64-bit Windows 10. And I found error occurring again. 
I tried setting the g.region to the current using DEM with the following function.

"execGRASS("g.region",flags= "a", parameters=list(rast="DEM")"

The error function is:

> "execGRASS("r.stream.extract", flags="overwrite",
>     parameters=list(elevation="DEM", accumulation="Accumulation", 
>     threshold=round(AT_mean[[i]], digit=0), mexp=0.01,
>     stream_rast="Stream_Comparison"))"

and the error is as follows:

"Current region rows: 8129, cols: 10704
ERROR: G_malloc: unable to allocate 696102528 bytes of memory at main.c:259
Warning message:
running command 'r.stream.extract.exe --overwrite elevation=DEM accumulation=Accumulation threshold=6 mexp=0.01 stream_rast=Stream_Comparison' had status 1"

I tried solving it in many ways such as, allocating memory using memory.limit(), setting up the computational region and also dividing the DEM into half. But nothing was successful.

Comment: Are your tools also 64bit (R, grass, any other plugins, etc...)? Any 32 bit process will be [limited to 2GB of RAM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#memory_limits) regardless of how much RAM the machine has, even if the operating system is 64bit.

Comment: Your threshold value looks VERY low to me. with 8000X10000 pixels, you have over 80 million cells. With a threshold of 6 you will be trying to create more than 10 million tiny drainage areas and stream reaches.

Comment: @EvilGenius Thanks for the clarification. I spotted out that I am using 32 bit grass and unfortunately the version I required doesnt have a stable 64-bit version.

Comment: @Micha Yeah, I also found out that my DEM is wrongly projected and it is causing some inane accumulation values and threshold as well. Thank you for giving your insights on it.